# C++ Adding and Subtracting Time

Tags: c++, time, addition

I am working on a program that asks the user to enter a time.(Assuming time is in 12 hour mode) The program also can ask the user if they want to add or subtract time from the original time they entered.

For example,

```
void getTime(int &h, int &m, bool mode);
```

This would ask the user to enter an hour and minutes

such as h=7 and m=30 would display

```
the time is 7:30
```

I want to include another void function that allows a user to add or subtract time. If the user is displayed a menu, and the user selects add time, and enters

```
h=2 m=30
```

The new time should display

```
The new time is 10:00
```

I think I will need to include a while loop so that hours does not exceed 12 and minutes does not exceed 60, but I am confused on where to start.

Comment: You read about the `%` operator in your favourite book.

Comment: Working with time is [complicated](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time). Use a library if you can, if you can use C++11 you can use [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Comment: @molbdnilo yup mod should be the approach for this.

Comment: %  ->  modular arithmetic

Answer (score 0):

```
Time Addition steps :

1)Convert float to integer.
   Time1 is 7.30 x 100  = 730
   Time2 is 2.30 x 100  = 230

   Addition => Time3 is = 960

2) Use divide & module operator (/,%).
   minutes = 960 % 100 ; (60)
   hours   = 960 / 100 ; (9) 

3) check two condition:
    if(min== 60){
      hours+1;
      minutes=0; 
   }

   if(hour==12 && min==60){
      hours=1;
      minutes=0;
    }

4) final result is : 10.00
```